# R plotly change parameters directly within Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinyapps

I know I will probably get downgraded with the following question since I don't have a specific code to share, but I will still give it a shot.
I have a big shiny app that has tons of R plotly graphs.
I would like the users to be able to customize graphs line colors, line widths, axes colors and fonts directly within the Shiny app.
The only solution I'm currently aware of is adding some elements (like drop down boxes) on top of each plot that would allow the users to customize each plot a little bit.
However, this is clearly not scalable. I would need to add the same elements a ton of times, to each graph.
Is there a way to allow users to customize plots interactively directly within the shiny app?
I tried to google this question but I couldn't find anything.
Thank you.

Comment: The dropdown boxes aren't scalable because you'd have to repeat it for each graph, yes? You may already be aware, but shinymodules is a great way to reuse the same elements again and again: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: Thank you! I was actually not aware of modules.